# use of -- on HTML (such as class="btn btn--cta btn--red)

Tags: html, css

Can someone please explain me what is the purpose of using -- on ?

such as class="btn btn--red btn--cta"  and those classes were used for styling but i m not getting this at all ... could someone please explain with simplicity ?

Comment: i just want to know why classes used with -- ? why cant simply use btn-red class instead of btn--class ?

Comment: You'd have to ask the author. There's nothing special or invalid about using those characters

Comment: It's just a convention, could be e.g. BEM: http://getbem.com/naming/

Answer (score 1):

This is a methodology called BEM that is Block, Element and modifier. This methodology is used to help in understandig the relationship between html element and its css styling. For your taken example we can explain it like - button is a block and according to BEM when you are modifying one block with some style you have to use class as .block--(style type). In your case .button--red. For example if you need to modify size for a button you have to write class name like, .button--big or .button--small. See this below blog from css tricks.
https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/